# How do I detect "End of File" in Kryo?

Tags: java, kryo

I'm reading an unknown number of objects from a gzipped file in Kryo:

```
Input input = new Input(new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(inputFile)));
```

The problem is: How do I detect when I've read the last object from the file?  When I'm writing the objects I don't know in advance how many I will be writing, so I can't include a count of the objects at the start of the file.

I could have some kind of "dummy" object that I write at the end of the file to indicate that it's the last one, but that seems ugly.

Comment: What does it say in the Javadoc?

Answer (score 3):

Use Input#eof() after reading each object to check if you hit the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, input.eof() does not effectively detect EOF, for example, this code resulted in `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow`.

```
while (!input.eof())
{
    SomeClass someObject = kryo.readObject(input, SomeClass.class);
    // ...
}
```

As a workaround, I did something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        SomeClass someObject = kryo.readObject(input, SomeClass.class);
        // ...
    }
    catch(KryoException ke)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I was using the jar version 2.21, but eof worked with 2.22.cloudera.1.

Comment: Did you see this `Buffer underflow` ever since? I'm using 2.22 version but it seems the exception is still here. It appears from time to time. The code is not run from multiple threads. @NateS, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

For latest (3.0.3) kryo libraries you can use input.eof(). For older ones use input.available() with a cost of performance (Almost 8 times slower).

```
while(input.available() > 0){
  someObject = kryo.readObject(input, SomeClass.class);
  i++;
}
```